Can I reference external schemas in microservices with Prisma ORM?
Let's say I want to establish relationships between models in different services. For example, if Service Buyer needs to reference a model in Service Gig how could I do it ?
As for now I get this error Type "Gig" is neither a built-in type, nor refers to another model, custom type, or enum.
Maybe I could define Gig as a type here inside Buyer schema, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Buyer {
  id             String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  username       String
  email          String
  profilePicture String
  country        String
  isSeller       Boolean  @default(false)
  createdAt      DateTime

  purchasedGigs Gig?    @relation(fields: [gigId], references: [id])
  gigId         String? @db.ObjectId

  @@index([username, email])
}

